# How do I redirect a specific port for my subdomain to another IP address

Tags: apache, http, dns, subdomain

Ok so I have a domain registered, for these purposes I will refer to it as *mydomain.com*. 
I also have Shared Hosting (just fyi) so I may be restricted in doing what I am planning.

So basically I have a sub-domain, *gserver.mydomain.com*, which points to a directory on the Host server showing basically a seperate website for this subdomain displaying information about it's corresponding gameserver.

Since it's about a gameserver, naturally I would want *gserver.mydomain.com* to also direct users to the gameserver's IP but I can't have it both to the Web Server and Game Server in the zone record as they are seperate IPs.

If the gameserver listens on.. let's say port 2400, then is it possible to have *gserver.mydomain.com*:**2400** point to another IP (the gameserver's IP) while still retaining the Web Hosts IP on port 80.

I have a general idea of how to go about it but with the current Hosting Plan, restrictions may be preventing me.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about DNS, it's not possible to use port (tcp or udp) information, as it handles only name/ip's (basicaly).
So, gserver.mydomain.com will always be resolved to the IP in the DNS database, regardless of the :port. Actualy, the :port is not part of the DNS name.
If all of your server will be HTTP servers and you have access to an Apache web servers, you can use something like proxy_pass.
You can take a look at this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass